# Indicate that a user is moderator or staff using icons

Tags: script, users

### About

This script implements the suggestion from [user1306322](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/183800/user1306322) to [Add an immediately visible indication that a user is a staff member or an employee of SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344033), which was the original request that led to [New Staff and Mod Labels on site metas and Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367899/new-staff-and-mod-labels-on-site-metas-and-meta-stack-exchange)

### Screenshot

It turns this:
[image: Before with trailing boxes]

into this:
[image: After with icons]
on front pages and on posts.

Note: The script excludes user profiles.

##### Community

Since version 0.6, the Community user also gets its own icon:
[image: A comment by Community]

and works in reviews too.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager with any of the major browsers.
Tested using [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) with Opera.

### Contact

For any bug, please post here. Comments are fine too.

### Code

JavaScript using jQuery

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackModerators%26Staff) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackModerators%26Staff/StackModerators%26Staff.user.js)

#### Sites

It is set to works on both Stack Overflow (main & meta) and on Meta Stack Exchange. But it can easily be expanded to any other meta site by adding two lines to the user script header:

```js
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?<siteurl>/
// @exclude      /^https://(?:meta\.)?<siteurl>/users/
```

Example for [Super User](https://superuser.com/):

```js
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?superuser\.com/
// @exclude      /^https://(?:meta\.)?superuser\.com/users/
```